# Add linux headers in gcc command

Tags: c, linux, gcc, g++, kernel

So I'm trying to include some headers in a c file on ubuntu16.04.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "list.h"
#include "phypages.h"
#include "pagetable.h"
```

It has the error:

```
fatal error: list.h: No such file or directory
```

I found all linux header files are in the

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-164/include/linux
```

So I use -I to include

```
gcc XXX.c -o XXX -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-164/include/linux
```

But then has the error

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-164/include/linux/stddef.h:4:31: fatal error: uapi/linux/stddef.h: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Kernel headers are not intended to be included in non-kernel sources.  Are you trying to write a kernel module?  But kernel modules need to be written for a freestanding implementation.  They cannot use most standard library headers or any standard library functions.

Comment: the posted code is 'C', not 'C++', strongly suggest removing the 'g++' tag

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using;

```
gcc XXX.c -o XXX -I/usr/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-164/include/linux
```

so the 'normal' C header files are searched before searching the linux header files

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it #include<list.h>, not #include"list.h"?